# What is the relationship between a pulsars period and the frequency?

Tags: astronomy, frequency, pulsars

If I measured the period at several of frequencies for a pulsar using a radio telescope what relationship should i see?

Comment: are you referring to the frequency of light in the pulses or the frequency of the pulses themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the frequency of the light in the pulse there is no relation between it and the times of the pulses. But if you are referring to the frequency of the pulses, in pulses per second, you get a $\frac{1}{time}$ relationship. The period of the pulses is $ \frac{1}{frequency}$.

If you measure 5 pulses in a second the frequency is 5 pulses/sec, and then the period is 1/5 of a second.

Comment: Yes I was referring to first part. Thanks